# ExifInterface FileNotFoundException /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200319_211738.jpg

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-file, android-exifinterface

After capturing an image from the Android Emulator in Android Studio i get a content URI and through that i want to proccess the Image. One of that proccess is that i want to modify the orientation. So i have a function that does that

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun modifyOrientation(bitmap: Bitmap, imagePath: String): Bitmap {
        val ei = ExifInterface(File(imagePath).absolutePath)

        return when (ei.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL
        )) {
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotate(bitmap, 90L.toFloat())

            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotate(bitmap, 180L.toFloat())

            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotate(bitmap, 270.toFloat())

            else -> bitmap
        }
    }
```

The value of imagePath is

```
imagePath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200319_211738.jpg"
```

However i get an exception in the ExifInterface(File(imagePath).absolutePath) line..!

```
Method threw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' exception.
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

What am i doing wrong..?

Comment: "i get a content URI" -- then perhaps you should use the `Uri` directly, with a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` that you can pass to the Jetpack edition of `ExifInterface`. "What am i doing wrong..?" -- you do not have access to that file.

Comment: Hmm...ok. Piece of code or an example would be really appreciated my friend. Thank you

Comment: How you get imagePath. You can look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60757833/8956604). It can be help you.