# Result for MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is always -1 but no data is returned

Tags: android, android-camera, mediastore

I am trying to choose/capture an image from gallery/camera(respectively) using the following code:

```
val pickIntent = Intent()
        pickIntent.type = "image/*"
        pickIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        val takePhotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        val pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle)
        chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(takePhotoIntent)
        )
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

However, I always get result code for activity as -1 when the `onActivityResult` function is invoked. I seem to have data when the gallery option is used by nothing when the camera is invoked.

I dont have any exception to return and don't know what to debug.

I am using an emulator to test my application.

Comment: You can look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60757833/8956604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'result code for activity as -1' means that `RESULT_OK`.
Use '.getData()' to retrieve the result, and decide what you want to do with it.

```
    switch (requestCode) {
      case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
          } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
      } break;
      default: break;
    }
```

Comment: But I no data in return from the camera

Comment: added some more info to the question