# image does not show in the image view

Tags: android, kotlin

I use the emulator which defined as pixel 2, and use the image is from the gallery and taken by the emulator. The permission part works fine, but after I selected the image, there is no image set in the imageView. I have already tried to search online and adjusted my original code, such as change setImageURI to ImageDecode to create bitmap. I am a new bee on kotlin, so could you help me?
Here is my xml file and code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PostActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/post_title"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/post_description"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/post_submit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/add_btn" />


</RelativeLayout>







class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageButton: ImageView?= null
//    private val GALLERY_REQUEST = 1

    companion object {
        private val PERMISSION_CODE = 1000
        private val IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.tool_bar))

        imageButton = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_button)
        imageButton!!.setOnClickListener {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    var permissions= arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                } else {
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                }
            } else {
                pickImageFromGallery()
            }
        }



    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && requestCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
//            imageButton?.setImageURI(data?.data)
            if (data != null) {
                val contentURI = data.data
                try{
                    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, contentURI!!)
                    val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                    imageButton?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

                } catch(e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.post_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.action_setting) {
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure data.data is not null?

Comment: You can look my answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60757833/8956604). It works fine.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir By your instruction, I set several log info in my code and find the "requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && requestCode== Activity.RESULT_OK" is false. Could you help me more about this? By the way, I will read your answer in the link you provided for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I recheck the requestCode. In my understanding, since the Activity.RESULT_OK has been set as -1 (from android develop doc) requestCode==Activity.RESULT_OK cannot be true if I get the correct requestCode. However, it is included in your code from your replying. Therefore, I am so confused about that. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir never mind. I am so stupid that I type the resultCode to requestCode. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Not at all, good luck.